# Инициализация односвязного списка

Tags: c++

```
Что-то не так передаю -_-

 #include <conio.h>
    #include <vector>
    #include <cmath>
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    struct A
    {
        int year;
        int maps;
    };

    struct List
    {
        A a;
        List* begin;
        List* next;
        List *tec=NULL,*start=NULL,*last=NULL;
    };

    void Innit(List** begin,int n )
    {
        *begin = new List;

        struct List *tec=NULL,*start=NULL,*last=NULL;


       for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {

            cin>>(*begin)->a.year;
            cin>>(*begin)->a.maps;

            if(start==NULL) //если вводиться первый элемент запомнить его в start
            {
                start=tec;
                last=tec;
            }
            last->next=tec;//в последнем элементе устанавливаю ссылку на новый
            last=tec;//новый элемент делаю последним
            last->next=NULL;//обнуляю ссылку в новом элементе
        }


        tec=start;


        for( int i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {
            cout<<(tec->a.year)<<endl;
            cout<<(tec->a.maps) << endl;
            tec=(tec->next);
        }
        getch();

    }

    int main()
    {
        int n;
        List* begin = NULL;


        cout<<"Vvedite kol-vo elementov spiska ";
        cin>>n;

          Innit(&begin,n);
    }
```

Comment: Воспользуйтесь `forward_list` зачем велосипед писать? во вторых непонятно где проблема и в чем.

Comment: Да еще и костыльный, прости если обидил.

Comment: Ну мне нужен свой костыль)

Answer (score 0):

Создание новой связки `*begin = new List;` в начале проги убрать, это нужно делать в цикле, где условие `if(start==NULL)`. Первым действием в цикле нужно создать новую связку списка `tec=new List`. Записывать данные с консоли нужно не в начало списка, а только-что созданную структуру `List`. И убери из структуры глобальные переменные `List *tec=NULL,*start=NULL,*last=NULL;`. Дальше прога кажется будет дышать.